# Limitation of beautifulsoap

Tags: beautifulsoup

I am trying to convert xml to JSON using Beautifulsoup for the xml file having structure as below:

```
<H3 id="LinkTarget_311">ISSS.1.A1Acceptance of Overall(B)</H3>

<Standard>An organisation's Top Management.</Standard>

<Standard>The Top Management MUST define.</Standard>

<H3 id="LinkTarget_3116">ISS.2.A2Acceptance of Overall(C)</H3>

<Standard>An organisation's Top.</Standard>

<Standard>Top Management.</Standard>

<H3 id="LinkTarget_316">ISS.2.2Acceptance of Overall(D)</H3>

<Standard>An organisation's Top resource.</Standard>

<Standard>Top Management resource.</Standard>
......
.......
```

The code I wrote is as below :

```
extract2 = re.compile(r"[A-Z][a-z]\w*")

control_ids = {}
header = bs_content.find_all('h3',{'id':True})
sub = bs_content.find_all('standard')

for i,j in zip(header,sub):
      
    req_id = str.strip(re.split(extract2,i.text)[0])
      
    control_ids[req_id] = j.text
```

The result is too long I an not paste all of it:

Expected result: text of H3 tag paired with text of the following 'standard' tags

`[{ISSS.1.A1Acceptance of Overall(B) : 'An organisation's Top Management.Top Management.'} , {ISS.2.A2Acceptance of Overall(C):'An organisation's Top.Top Management.'},....]`

Answer (score 0):

Try something simpler:

```
ids = bs_content.select('H3')
for id in ids:
    value = " ".join([stan.text for stan in id.fetchNextSiblings()[:2]])
    control_ids[id.text] = value
print(control_ids)
```

Output, based on your sample html:

```
{'ISSS.1.A1Acceptance of Overall(B)': "An organisation's Top Management. The Top Management MUST define.", 
'ISS.2.A2Acceptance of Overall(C)': "An organisation's Top. Top Management.",  
'ISS.2.2Acceptance of Overall(D)': "An organisation's Top resource. Top Management resource."}
```